# My sir said that work done by external force to move a charge in the absence of electric field is zero, i tried to search about it but i got nothing?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, charge, potential

Today my sir started a new chapter, electric potential and capacitance, and in the very start of the lecture, my sir said that it's not necessary that work must be done to move a charge, I asked sir why ? he said, if there is no electric field, then work done by electric field will be zero, but I am not able to get it because I am thinking as work done = integral of F●ds, so a work must be done if you are moving a charge. where am I wrong ?

Comment: In what country are teachers or professors called "My Sir?"  Or is it a translation thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if there is an electric field, the work you do to move a charge to a point with the same potential is still zero, unless you have added kinetic energy to the charge. By the work-energy theorem, the total work done on the charge is the change in kinetic energy:

$$\int\limits_A^B (\vec F_\text{ext}+\vec F_e)\cdot d\vec\ell=\Delta K $$
where $\vec F_\text{ext}$ is the external force that you apply, $\vec F_e=q\vec E$ is the electrostatic force on charge $q$ due to the electric field $\vec E$, and $\Delta K$ is the difference in kinetic energies at points $B$ and $A$, which we will take to be zero. The work you do in this process is

$$\int\limits_A^B \vec F_\text{ext}\cdot d\vec\ell=-q\int\limits_A^B \vec E\cdot d\vec\ell = q(V_B-V_A)$$
which is zero if the potentials at $A$ and $B$ are equal.

Comment: Thank you sir, actually my teacher gave me answer to my question today after teaching about potential and potential energy. and your answer is very clear after what sir explained today, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no electric field:

$${\bf F}=0$$

so the integral over $d{\bf s}$ is also zero.

Comment: The OP is concerned with the work done by an external force, not the electric force. You have just reposted what the OPs professor told them that they are confused by.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "move a charge" is too ambiguous here. You have to specify the type of movement.

The professor is most likely considering the case where the particle is moving at a constant velocity. If there is no electric field, you don't need an external force to keep it moving at that constant velocity, so $F=0$. If there is an electric field, the external force needs to balance the electric force, and so there is an external force that does work.

Comment: yes, i got your point, i will verify it with my professor. and thanks for answering. cheers.